# How do I enable the touchscreen in 22.04 on my HP laptop?

Tags: drivers, laptop, hp, touchscreen

I recently bought a new laptop and the touchscreen is not recognized in Ubuntu. I am not sure how to proceed as on my old laptop (also an HP) and work laptop (a Lenovo) the touchscreens worked perfectly out of the box. I am hoping the below information will help to figure this out.

Edit: It is a HP Pavilion Laptop PC 15-eg2000

Output of `hostnamectl`

```
    ...
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.10                    
              Kernel: Linux 5.19.0-41-generic
        Architecture: x86-64
    Firmware Version: F.11
```

Output of `lspci`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 04)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b0 (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 5017 (rev 03)
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 30c9:0065 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3567 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the model of your laptop

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it is a HP Pavilion Laptop PC 15-eg2000

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi what other information would be helpful?

Comment: Can you give Ubuntu 23.04 a try? Since it has a newer kernel, it should have better support for recent hardware

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I updated and it still doesn't work

Comment: Hello, I am having a similar issue on my HP laptop too. Is this fixed?